# Resource request: Stone-Čech construction generalized

Tags: general-topology, compactification

I was looking at the wikipedia article on the [Stone-Čech compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification), and read that...

> The Stone–Čech construction can be performed for more general spaces $X$, but the map $X \to \beta X$ need not be a homeomorphism to the image of $X$ (and sometimes is not even injective).

Despite $X \to \beta X$ possibly not being an embedding for general $X$, the article says functoriality and the same universal property will hold in the general case, and since I am currently self-studying categorical adjunctions, I think I would like to see the general "Stone-Čech construction".

After searching online, though, I can't seem to find a resource that explains a construction for *non*-Tychonoff spaces. Can anyone tell me where I can find a general construction - maybe in lecture notes, a free online resource, or a part of a book, etc?

Comment: The construction is literally exactly the same, and so are all the proofs.  You just can't prove that the map $X\to\beta X$ is an embedding, which is the only step that uses the assumption that $X$ is Tychonoff.

Comment: @EricWofsey What construction do you mean: embeddings into $[0,1]^X$ don't work, but maximal zero-set ultrafilters maybe? But maybe all continuous maps on $X$ are constant, so there is only one zero-set? It might get trivialised..

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: I don't know what you mean by embeddings into $[0,1]^X$.  There are indeed many different constructions, but every single one I can think of works just as well for arbitrary spaces (tupling together all maps $X\to [0,1]$, ultrafilters on zero sets, spectrum of $C_b(X)$, ...).  If all continuous functions on $X$ are constant, then $\beta X$ is just a point; there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @EricWofsey I meant what you call "tupling together all maps from $X$ into $[0,1]$". In a category sense there is indeed no problem, it's just a morphism (then constant). But the interpretation is gone. For me, the Stone-Cech is an "extension" of $X$. So Wikipedia is right, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the following construction technique still works (which I think is the original Tychonoff one): for any space $X$ let $\mathcal{F}$ be 
the set $\mathcal{F} = \{f: X \to [0,1]: f \text{ continuous}\}$. This a well-defined set and non-empty  (which could consist of only constant the functions for some spaces $X$, but these are always in $\mathcal{F}$.)

Define $P_X = [0,1]^{\mathcal{F}}$ as the set $\{g: \mathcal{F} \to [0,1]\}$ in the product topology, so that it has the smallest topology that makes all $\pi_f: P_X \to [0,1]$ continuous (where $\pi_f(g) = g(f)$). By Tychonoff's theorem, $P_X$ is a compact space (it's just a product of many copies of $[0,1]$ which is compact) and it's also Hausdorff (all product of Hausdorff spaces are).

Then define $e_X: X \to P_x$ (the evaluation map, a.k.a Gelfand transform, I believe) by $(e_X(x))(f) = f(x)$ for all $f \in \mathcal{F}$, note that $e_X(x)$ should be a member of the product, so a function $\mathcal{F} \to [0,1]$, so we specify what its value is on each $f$.

By the universal property of maps into the product, $e_X$ is a continuous function of $X$ to $P_X$, as $\pi_f(e) = f$ for all $f \in \mathcal{F}$. For Tychonoff spaces $e_X$ is an embedding by the theorem: $e_X$ is an embedding into $P_X$ iff

- $\mathcal{F}$ separates points: $\forall x \neq y \in X: \exists f \in \mathcal{F}: f(x) \neq f(y)$.
- $\mathcal{F}$ separates points from closed sets: $\forall x \in X: \forall C \subseteq X: x \notin C \text{ and } C \text{ closed} \implies \exists f \in \mathcal{F}: f(x) \notin \overline{f[C]}$.

The first condition is just a restatement of injectivity. The second ensures that the inverse (which then exists) from $e[X]$ to $X$ is continuous. This argument works for all spaces. And $\mathcal{F}$ obeys these conditions for a space $X$, iff $X$ is Tychonoff. (We can state and prove this embedding theorem for any family of maps, and the product of the codomains, mutatis mutandis.)

$\beta X:= \overline{e_X[X]} \subseteq P_X$ and $e = e_X: X \to P_X$ considered as a map to $\beta X$ (codomain restriction, which does not impact continuity).

Then $\beta X$ is compact Hausdorff, as a closed subset of the compact $P$, so $\beta X$ lies in the right category, and we need to see that the pair $(X,e)$ is universal for maps to compact Hausdorff spaces.

The proof of the universal property (existence part) uses that all compact Hausdorff $K$ embed into a product $P_K=[0,1]^{\mathcal{F}'}$ of copies of $[0,1]$ as well, using the above construction with $\mathcal{F}'$ as the set of continuous maps from $K$ into $[0,1]$, as all such $K$ are Tychonoff (even $T_4$). So the map $e_K: K \to P_K$ for some product of $[0,1]$ is a homeomorphism when restricted as $e_K: K \to e_K[K] = \beta K$ (the latter as $e_K[K]$ is already compact in the Hausdorff product $P_K$, so closed, so its closure, i.e. $\beta K$, is just $e_K[K]$ itself.

Now, if $f: X \to K$ is any continuous map from $X$ to a compact Hausdorff $K$: consider the following: For every continuous map $f': K \to [0,1]$, we have that $f' \circ f: X \to [0,1]$, is also continuous, so lies in $\mathcal{F}$. Define $h$ from $P_X$ to $P_K$ by $h(g)(f') = g(f' \circ f)$, where $g \in P_X = [0,1]^{\mathcal{F}}$, and $f' \in \mathcal{F}'$. Then check that $h' = h|_{\beta X} \circ e_X$ maps $X$ into $e_K[K]$, as $h'(x) = e_K[f(x)]$ for all $x \in X$. Then define $\beta f: X \to K: \beta f := e_K^{-1} \circ h'$ which is continuous as $e_K$ is a homeomorphism, and note that $\beta f \circ e = f$, as required. The unicity is similar, as the condition $\beta f \circ e = f$ forces what $\beta f$ has to be on $e[X]$, and this is thus uniquely determined on the closure (as $K$ is Hausdorff and $e[X]$ is by definition dense in $\beta X$).

There are probably books that do it this way too, but I wouldn't be able to name one. All that I checked (Engelking, Herrlich, and some more) only worked within Tychonoff spaces, and then $(\beta X, e)$ is a compactification. For me, this is more natural, but the construction still works in general. Note that if $X$ only has constant continuous maps to $[0,1]$, $\beta X$ is just a singleton, and $e$ is the unique constant map to it. So it's not as intuitive any more.

I found one online reference,  in Tom Leinster's book "basic category theory" where he discusses a general theorem (Special Adjoint Functor Theorem, SAFT). In 6.3.14 he derives the existence of a left adjoint for the forgetful functor from $\textrm{CompHaus}$ to $\textrm{Top}$, which is the Stone-Cech construction. He does mention there the construction as the closure of the image of $X$ under the canonical map from $X$ into $[0,1]^{C(X,[0,1])}$, but does not mention whether this always holds or only for Tychonoff spaces (which he calls "a mild separation property")..

Finally, [this nice blog post](https://etreseul.wordpress.com/2015/03/06/ultrafilters-i-the-stone-cech-compactification/) explicitly says the construction I just gave is the general one that works for all $X$... I don't know whether this counts as a "reference", though (it has the same status as this answer in a way).

Intuitively, we'd like use a "set" $\mathbb{C} = \{f: X \to K\}$ where $f$ is continuous and $K$ ranges over *all* compact Hausdorff (cH) spaces, and define an $e_X$ as before into a product over all cH spaces, and then $f$ factors over $e_X$ by $\pi_f$ essentially. This doesn't really work, as we get proper classes, but luckily $[0,1]$ is a so-called "generator'" for this class cH, so maps into $[0,1]$ suffice.

Comment: I appreciate your answer! I'm going to go over everything to make sure I fully understand

Comment: Excellent job. Just going over the last bit but it looks like it all works out. Thanks again!

Comment: @joeb glad to help. This construction took me back to one of my first topology classes by prof. Maurice, an excellent teacher. He only did it for Tychonoff spaces, as the classical case. I was also curious how much would still work.